# Can't click on two buttons at the same time on gaming mouse

Tags: hardware, mouse

When I play Fortnite i want to build quick. I noticed that my gaming mouse "Star Raider CND-SGM1" doesn't recognize when I FIRST hold my left click and than I click on "back key" on the side of my mouse AT THE SAME TIME. All other combinations of clicking and holding works... I uploded a picture of what keys I mean here:
[image]

I tried to test my mouse here https://unixpapa.com/js/testmouse.html, but this specific combination also doesn't work.

I know about keyboard ghosting. But I guess that mice have same problem?

My question is... if your gaming mice have the same problem and how do I know which mice have this problem and which don't?

Comment: Are you holding down on the back mouse button?

Comment: My son is a very experienced fortnite player (Diamond II atm!) and had exactly this problem with cheap mice from Amazon, and another mouse supplied with a gaming PC. Said mice had all the side buttons and wheel, so looked fine from afar, but less so when played with. The only solution was to buy him a Logitech gaming mouse - I got him the cheapest, a G203, for 25 quid or so, and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already mentioned yourself, this is most likely a ghosting problem. Not quite ghosting, but rather jamming. But these are both [rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)) problems

"Gaming" mice often register themselves as additional keyboard device to your operating system and they can suffer from the same problems. Either your hardware can't handle the combination of certain keys, or the driver on your computer is not fit to recegnize given combination. (some source [here](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/g9x-blackwidow-tournament-edition-lan-party,3359-5.html))

It seems like your mouse is of medium quality and does not provide proper key rollover for the thumb buttons. I dont't think there is much you can do besides ensuring that your driver is up to date.